# How to get all the pixels of a specific color from a png in an imageview

Tags: android, canvas, mask, pixel

I am trying to get all the pixels of a specific colour from an image in an imageview. Is it even possible to do something like that? if so, please point me in correct direction. Below is my image[image]

I need all the pixels where the red dots are and all the pixels of green dots. Is this possible? I don't need to know the color of a given pixel. I need to print all the pixels that contains red dots. Thanks. Please don't vote if the question isn't clear.

Comment: iterate through your bitmap's pixels, and check their colors

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily transform your picture in a grayscale and depict it in an histogram. There each pixel is assigned to an corresponding value between 0-255. With this informations you can extract all red and green pixels.

You should looking for OpenCV4Android:

Here is an general overview of OpenCV:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html

Installing guide for Android:
https://medium.com/@sukritipaul005/a-beginners-guide-to-installing-opencv-android-in-android-studio-ea46a7b4f2d3

And here is an example project:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/image-manipulations/src/org/opencv/samples/imagemanipulations/ImageManipulationsActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all the pixels and check their color as Vladyslav Matviienko said.

1. Display your picture
2. Create a dictionary
3. Iterate over all your pixels
4. Get the color of the current pixel
5. If your dictionary already contains the current color, add it to the array (which key is the color)
6. If the dictionary doesn't contain the current color, instantiate an array (which key is the color) then add the color to it.

Example:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pixels;

function draw(canvas, ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 10, 3, 3);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#00f';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 0, 3, 3);
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 3, 3);
}

function getPixelsByColors(canvas, ctx) {
    let pixel;
    let color;
    let dict = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < canvas.height; j++) {
            pixel = ctx.getImageData(i, j, 1, 1);
            color = getColorFromPixel(pixel);
            if (!dict[color]) {
                dict[color] = [];
            }
            dict[color].push({ x: i, y: j });
        }
    }
    return dict;
}

function getColorFromPixel(pixel) {
    let red = pixel.data[0];
    let green = pixel.data[1];
    let blue = pixel.data[2];
    let alpha = pixel.data[3];
    let color = red + '-' + green + '-' + blue + '-' + alpha;
    return color;
}

draw(canvas, ctx);
pixels = getPixelsByColors(canvas, ctx);
console.log('pixels', pixels);
```

Try it (here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/5mhsyw3v/15/) which displays the dictionary's content in the console).